# Loading indicator remains Worklight application on Android

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have asked a question this.. 
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=470749

Is there any temporary fix or workaround to stop this unless waiting next fix pack ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can invoke

```
setTimeout(function(){
   WL.Client.__hideBusy();
}, 500);
```

from your wlEnvInit function.